# Rails includes return characters in environment variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, environment-variables

I'm storing environment variables in `/etc/environment` like:

```
FACEBOOK_API_KEY=XXXXXXXXXXX
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET=XXXXXXXXXX
```

But when i access the ENV variable through Rails i get this:

```
ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY']
=> XXXXXXXXX\r
```

Notice the `\r`, How to get rid of that without cleaning up each and every call to ENV vars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**figaro**](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) to manage your ENV variables.

It creates a `config/application.yml` file for you that should not be checked into version control.

```
# config/application.yml
FACEBOOK_API_KEY:    XXXXXXXXXXX
FACEBOOK_API_SECRET: XXXXXXXXXX
```

Variables will be available at `ENV['FACEBOOK_API_KEY']` as you are used to.

An alternative would be [configatron](https://github.com/markbates/configatron).

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're getting a `\r` because you're editing `/etc/environment` using a Windows text editor and installing it on a Unix system (or possibly using Cygwin in Windows, but the same applies).  Or you copied/pasted it from a source that did that.  In any case, something has introduced a CRLF into a Unix file that only wants LF line-endings.

If it is an editor, you'll want to fix it to stop using Windows CRLF (`\r\n`) line endings, and use Unix LF (`\n`) line endings.  Notepad++ has an option for this, as do many other editors and IDEs.  Google around for yours and find out how to use Unix line endings.  You'll run into a ton of problems like this otherwise.

You can fix the existing file by running it through a program like `dos2unix` (on a Unix system; you may have to install the package), or using a simple `tr` command like this:

**Edit: fixed the filename order in the `mv` command below.**

```
tr -d '\r' </etc/environment >/tmp/environment
# <verify new file looks good>
mv /tmp/environment /etc/environment
```

Please be careful, make backups, check the file, etc.

You can make sure there aren't any rogue `\r` characters in your file by looking at an octal dump:

```
od -c /tmp/environment
```

Look for any `\r` in the output.